# Is it possible to use qsub for distribution of job on machine having multiple core ?

Tags: multithreading, pbs, qsub, torque

Can I use qsub for distribution of jobs on machine having multiple
core ?

My machine has 8 cores and is it possible to distribute job (set of different programs) using PBS server on these 8 cores separately?

if not, Is there any other alternate of this. Main script of the program use qsub to distribute 6 different jobs on nodes when using in parallel mode but when user won't opt for parallel option it use the only one core not other.

Answer (score 1):

> My machine has 8 cores and is it possible to distribute job (set of different programs) using PBS server on these 8 cores separately?

qsub is a part of torque.  Torque is simply a scheduler.  Torque does not distribute tasks itself.  It is up to the users to do those things.

Depending on what you need to do you might look at using MPI or OpenMP.

If each task is it's own command you can spawn each task and they will automatically use the available processors, as they are able to.